# regex: validate european date format with multiple separators

Tags: regex

I want to validate european date formats like "10.02.2012" or "10-02-2012". Therefore I created the following regex:

```
/\d[0-9]{2}(.|-)\d[0-9]{2}(.|-)\d[0-9]{4}/
```

Unfortunately I always get the message not valid, even when the date has the right format.

When I replace the "(.|-)" with "." for validating only dates separated with a dot it works. So i guess the problem must be the "(.|-)"
Any ideas?

Comment: dot needs to be escaped, as \. to mean the literal . character, although it should still match correctly, it would just fail to filter other separator characters than . or -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works correctly after minor modifications :

```
\d{2}(\.|-)\d{2}(\.|-)\d{4}
```

1. the "." needs to be escaped.
2. \d is same as [0-9] , no need to repeat it.

http://regexr.com?326f2

Comment: just tried this in the ruby-console, but it did not work as well: `1.9.3-p0 :055 > regex = /d{2}(\.|\-)\d{2}(\.|\-)\d{4}/
 => /d{2}(\.|\-)\d{2}(\.|\-)\d{4}/ 
1.9.3-p0 :056 > string = "20.10.2012"
 => "20.10.2012" 
1.9.3-p0 :057 > if string =~ regex
1.9.3-p0 :058?>   puts "correct"
1.9.3-p0 :059?>   else
1.9.3-p0 :060 >     puts "false"
1.9.3-p0 :061?>   end
false
 => nil `

Comment: Better use a character class, that's what they're there for: `\d{2}[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d{4}`. Bonus: No need to escape the dot.

Comment: many thanks, but even if the regex is correct now, it unfortunately still not work in the ruby context. But I suppose this is a ruby-related question then

Answer (score 10):

Note that the answers provided so far using the \d character class will allow dates such as 00.00.0000 or 99.99.9999 to pass through. If you want to catch this, you need to use a more specific regex. The one below would allow valid dates between 01.01.1900 and 31.12.2099

```
^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[-\.](19|20)\d\d$
```

If you want to allow any year from 0000 to 9999, then you could change it to

```
^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[-\.]\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I see your problem...

```
/\d[0-9]{2}(.|-)\d[0-9]{2}(.|-)\d[0-9]{4}/
```

is redundant, in that \d is the same as [0-9], so actually here you are matching for 3 digits not 2. Try

```
/\d{2}(\.|-)\d{2}(\.|-)\d{4}/
```

or

```
/[0-9]{2}(\.|-)[0-9]{2}(\.|-)[0-9]{4}/
```

but don't use both