# Regex for french date doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, regex

Here is my code:

```js
$('#test').on('click',function(){
var regdate = new RegExp('^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2})$|^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2}\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$');

if (regdate.test($('#datepicker').val()))
{
    $('#response').text("Okay");
}
else
{
    $('#response').text("Nooo");
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control noColorFocus" name="dateMinChargement" id="datepicker" />
<button id="test">Valider</button>
<div id="response"></div>
```

A date like `17/01/2017` should return `true` when we try to `regdate.test()`… Any idea?

Comment: I think your regex expression may be a bit too verbose. Here are some simple solutions, check out this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472976/regex-validate-european-date-format-with-multiple-separators 
 you may need to replace the separation characters with some escaped slashes.

Comment: You mean backslashes?

Comment: No, I mean escaped slashes so your validator will catch 1/2/2013 instead of 1-2-2013 or 1.2.2013. i.e.\/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a regex you have two options:

1. String: `new RegExp('...')` where the backslashes needs to be escaped
2. Direct: `/MyPattern/` where backslashes aren't an issue anymore:

```js
$('#test').on('click',function(){
var regdate = /^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2})$|^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2}\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$/;

if (regdate.test($('#datepicker').val()))
    $('#response').text("Okay");
else
    $('#response').text("Nooo");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control noColorFocus" name="dateMinChargement" id="datepicker" />
<button id="test">Valider</button>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: @Kuartz glad about that! *Bonne chance*