# Regex to check a valid number in a format in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if the string is in the following format

1. YYMMDD-XXXX
2. YYYYMMDD-XXXX
3. YYMMDDXXXX
4. YYYYMMDDXXXX

I have this regex

```
^\d{6,8}(-\d{4})?$
```

But then I am stuck. I am really new at regex. Can I get some help or some pointers?

Comment: It is more complicated then you think. For example, month can be between 01 - 12, and not arbitrary 2 digits.

Comment: for now I don't need to check that months etc are correct. So 111111-1111 is correct.

Comment: How about you actually parse the dates as dates instead? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: If any of the answers resolved your issue please mark one so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function checkFunc($value){
  if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{6,8}(-?)[0-9]{4}$/', $value)) {
    //is valid
     return $value;
  } else {
    //is invalid
    return false;
 }
}

echo checkFunc("20180529-4444"); //20180529-4444
```

but for the first part of string, you will have to create different check for the date format

Answer (score 3):

Make the `-` optional and your regex works:

```
^\d{6,8}(-?\d{4})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/uoF1HM/1/

This also would match many number formats though. Your example strings look like dates, if that is the case I'd use something stricter ( or already written e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566624/3783243 might be a good place to start).

Answer (score 0):

In your regex [`^\d{6,8}(-\d{4})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bQhqww/1) youy have an optional group `(-\d{4})?` with a hyphen inside the group. That means that you can only match a format like `\d{6,8}` or with a hyphen `\d{6,8}-\d{4}` but not `\d{6,8}\d{4}` because the hyphen should be there according to the optional group.

If you want to match your values without any capturing groups you could make only the dash optional `?`

That would match

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\d{6,8}` Match 6 - 8 digits
- `-?` Match optional dash
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

  [`^\d{6,8}-?\d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/iyAZ66/1)